# How do I display only the last 5 transactions?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am using a script that converts SQL to Fox Pro (Visual Fox Pro and I generated code to show me a payment history. however I only want it to show the last 5 payments with that corresponding payments

This query will show all payments ever made.
I only need the last 5 payments

```
trns.trxdate = payment date
trns.payment = payment amount

'Trying to generate SIF/PIF report for Feb 2024
strsql = "SELECT dbt.ourfile, dbt.ncustfile, dbt.preourfile, dbt.assdate, dbt.sdate, dbt.jdate, debt.cdate, trns.trxdate, trns.payment FROM dbt JOIN trns ON dbt.ourfile = trns.ourfile where dbt.custid in ('C1495', 'C1196') AND dbt.cdate => {d'2024-02-01'} AND trns.trx in ('01', '02', '07', '09')"
```

The code above produces the following results, I am looking for a way to only show the most recent 5 transactions. Some accounts have hundreds of transactions.

![1]: https://imgur.com/a/Hz8U388.jpg "results of data pull"

My desired result is this (only showing the last 5 transactions)

![1]: https://imgur.com/P2QAC1D.jpg "desired results"

Any help would be appreciated. Google was not my friend when trying to find a solution.

I have tried to use grouping with MAX and CTE. I kept getting compilation errors when I executed the script.

Comment: Where is some sample data with desired result that shows what you want (from story it is hard to understand what you are asking)? And what is the backend that you are running this SQL against? Maybe not important, but what is VSP? This syntax is not for VFP, is it? Also the error messages mıght be helpful, in understanding the environment, target of "script" etc.

Comment: Especially this part of syntax left me in dark "dbt.cdate => {d'2024-02-01'}". What is the target backend to understand such a syntax? It is not VFP, nor one of the databases that I know of. It looks like a VFP date literal but it is not. Maybe more VBish attempt to write a date?

Comment: @CetinBasoz - I have updated my question.  VSP was a typo I meant VFP (Visual Fox Pro) - Our systems use a FoxPro data base and they hired a consultant to create a .vbs script that converts SQL to FoxPro. 

I have no guide to go by and the consultant is long gone. I typically work by pulling huge reports and paring them down in excel, power query .  This file is huge and was hoping for a way to cut clean up time.

Comment: While that is easy to do say with SQL server, I don't know an SQL that could do it against a VFP table in a single SQL call. However, if it is worth, and you have something like MS SQL server (express) installed, then you could get the data into a temp sql server table and do the query on it.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thanks for looking into it, I figured it was not possible (due to limitations)  but I was hoping. I can do the conversion in PowerQuery with a bit of cleanup because the initial data pull contains broken fields due to commas. What I mean by that is is instead of getting a result of: 
1510.50
The initial report produces: 
1
510.50

This is because it was somehow entered in as  1,510.50

The work is doable but I just figured if I could get the last 5 in the initial pull I could bypass it and save a lot of time. 

Thanks again

Comment: Assuming last 5 means 5 most recent, add TOP 5 after SELECT and add ORDER BY cDate DESC. Or run a new query against the initial result that applies those.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor yes it means top 5 but he wants it per customer Id. In other backends it is simple with say outer apply in MS SQL server and lateral in postgreSQL (or using row_number()). But in VFP I can't think of a single SQL to do that.

Comment: Right, you can't do that with a single SQL in VFP. (Well, you can, but it's really ugly and slow.) Typically, you use SQL plus some Xbase code for that in VFP.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the TOP 5 along with an ORDER BY DESCENDING. That should give you the most recent 5 transactions in descending order. If you need those 5 records in ascending order, you could do another query to reorder the results.

```
SELECT TOP 5 dbt.ourfile, dbt.ncustfile, dbt.preourfile, ;
    dbt.assdate, dbt.sdate, dbt.jdate, debt.cdate, ;
    trns.trxdate, trns.payment ;
    FROM dbt ;
    JOIN trns ;
    ON dbt.ourfile = trns.ourfile ;
    WHERE dbt.custid IN ('C1495', 'C1196') ;
    AND dbt.cdate => {d'2024-02-01'} ;
    AND trns.trx IN ('01', '02', '07', '09') ;
    ORDER BY trns.trxdate DESC
```